# when a <li> is clicked send clicked result to a href

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is what I have got so far, but instead of sending the result to a `<div>`, I need the result displaying inside a `<a href="Link-1"></a>` so that it is a link.

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

listItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.onclick = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = this.innerText;
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link-1</li>
  <li>Link-2</li>
  <li>Link-3</li>
  <li>Link-4</li>
  <li>Link-5</li>
</ul>

<div id="output"></div>
```

> new code added

```
<?php
  while ($conn = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>  
  <li><a href="/Link-1/<?php echo $conn["area"]; ?>/"><?php echo $conn["area"]; ?></a></li>
<?php }?>
```

The code above `<?php echo $conn["area"]; ?>` pulls a town out of a database.

**Thanks for pushing me in right direction. Is it possible to add php into the link as well?**

Comment: you need to put the text of output div on the each li, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the text content inside the `<li>` tags to be a link? Or put a link somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

listItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.onclick = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<a href="' + this.innerText + '">' + this.innerText +'</a>';
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link-1</li>
  <li>Link-2</li>
  <li>Link-3</li>
  <li>Link-4</li>
  <li>Link-5</li>
</ul>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `div` to an anchor and update the `textContent` as well as the `href` attribute.

In this updated answer, instead of adding a event listener to each list item, I've attached one to the list ([event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)). I can then use the `target` property of the event to identify which of the items was clicked and use the `textContent` from that element to update the anchor.

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('#anchor');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

list.addEventListener('click', changeAnchor, false);

function changeAnchor({ target: { textContent } }) {
  anchor.textContent = textContent;
  anchor.href = textContent;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Link-1</li>
  <li>Link-2</li>
  <li>Link-3</li>
  <li>Link-4</li>
  <li>Link-5</li>
</ul>

<a id="anchor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just retrieve the list-elements' text, set it to you anchor tag's `href` attribute with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) by wrapping the anchor tag within back-ticks referencing the inner text inside placeholders `${}` and then use the innerHTML property to add it to your `#output` div like this:

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
var output = document.getElementById('output');

listItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    output.innerHTML = `<a href="${item.innerText}">${item.innerText}</a>`;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link-1</li>
  <li>Link-2</li>
  <li>Link-3</li>
  <li>Link-4</li>
  <li>Link-5</li>
</ul>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the the link element by setting the specific property with the currently clicked element's text:

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    
    listItems.forEach(function(item) {
      item.onclick = function(e) {
        
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = this.innerText;         
        a.innerText = this.innerText;        
        document.getElementById('output').append(a);
        
      }
    });
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>Link-1</li>
      <li>Link-2</li>
      <li>Link-3</li>
      <li>Link-4</li>
      <li>Link-5</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="output"></div>
```